# Data not passing back to Pandas from nested function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to determine why the ultimate value produced by my function isn't being saved back to the new column I have instructed pandas to build.  I have confirmed the if...elif statements are correct and function, and I have confirmed the calculations are occurring and generating the correct data.  I am getting this result:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     1.0
6     NaN
7     1.0
8     1.0
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    NaN
Name: Result, dtype: float64
```

But expect to get

```
0.036231884058
0.18115942029
0.925
0.9255
0.962820512821
1.0
0.368421052632
1.0
1.0
0.950125944584
1.0
0.950125944584
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'Cr': [.1,.5,1,1.002,1.2,2,.79,3,3,4,400,4],
   'De': [.1,.2,.36,.47,.5,.16,.006,.07,.107,.6,1.7,2.17]
    } );

def Fin_adj(row, field):
    if field == 'Cr':
        if row[field] <= .7:
            Range_eval(row[field],0,.69,.0,.25)
        elif row[field] <= .9:
            Range_eval(row[field],.7,.89,.25,.5)
        elif row[field] <= 1.1:
            Range_eval(row[field],.9,1.10,.9,.95)
        elif row[field] <= 1.5:
            Range_eval(row[field],1.1,1.49,.95,1)
        elif row[field] <= 3:
            return 1
        else:
            Range_eval(row[field],3,data[field].max(),.95,1)

def Range_eval (val_in, Oldmin, Oldmax, Newmin, Newmax):
    (((val_in - Oldmin) * (Newmax - Newmin)) / (Oldmax - Oldmin)) + Newmin



df['Result'] = df.apply(Fin_adj, args=('Cr',), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot some `return` statements

```
def Fin_adj(row, field):
    if field == 'Cr':
        if row[field] <= .7:
            return Range_eval(row[field],0.,.69,.0,.25)
        elif row[field] <= .9:
            return Range_eval(row[field],.7,.89,.25,.5)
        elif row[field] <= 1.1:
            return Range_eval(row[field],.9,1.10,.9,.95)
        elif row[field] <= 1.5:
            return Range_eval(row[field],1.1,1.49,.95,1)
        elif row[field] <= 3.:
            return 1
        else:
            return Range_eval(row[field],3.,df[field].max(),.95,1)

def Range_eval (val_in, Oldmin, Oldmax, Newmin, Newmax):
    return (((val_in - Oldmin) * (Newmax - Newmin)) / (Oldmax - Oldmin)) + Newmin
```

Comment: Wow, thank you Alex. I feel like an idiot I could have sworn I tried it with and without.  I think I must have blanked on the return in Range_eval when I tested it.

Comment: we're here to learn. You'll remember `return`s sure enough!! ;-)